# derbyJS with canvas synchronisation example

Tags: derbyjs

Starting out with derbyJS.

I am looking for a working example (or directions) for a small derbyJS app that synchronizes the content of a canvas.

Something like [the multiplayer notepad screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0DOGXmaT3g#t=773), but using an HTML canvas.

Edit : I will only ever need to synchronise a 2D context. Also I would prefer a solution leveraging derbyJs, but at this point if you have another solution I may as well consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are doing. If you want to keep a game in sync you will typically need to re-render the whole canvas each time with the state of the game. For this I would maintain the state of the game inside Derby (world variables) and then push the new data out every frame update to the client. Alternatively you could have some clever incremental updates for other types of applications with canvas.

Comment: I'd love to hear about a "clever incremental update" solution. I bet it would be rather algorithmic, but if you have something I'd be happy to hear about it.